# How to retrieve only meetings?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to select only meetings (appointments with multiple people) in MS Graph (not necessarily *online* meetings). My guess is I would have to filter on the *attendees* collection not being empty.

- Is that assumption correct?
- How do I do that?

I have tried all kinds of variations on *attendees* like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '{{start_datetime}}' and end/dateTime le '{{end_datetime}}' and attendees.length ne 0
```

... but so far no success. (The `{{...}}` are Postman environment variables). All I get is

```
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid filter clause",
```

I have looked at [lambda operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but something like this also is an invalid filter <sup>**</sup>:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=attendees/any(e:e/emailAddress eq '')
```

Googling for "ms graph empty collection" gives me plenty of posts for people receiving no results, but that's not what I'm looking for. It also does not help that the terms "appointment" and "meeting" are used interchangeably ;-)

<sup>** Follow-up question: [Are lambda filters on subproperties of calendar event collections allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75554213/are-lambda-filters-on-subproperties-of-calendar-event-collections-allowed)</sup>

Update 24 Feb.:
As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75554492/512728) to that follow-up question I cannot uses *attendees*. The answer to my initial question *Is that assumption correct?* is **No**. Is there anything else I can filter on to retrieve only meetings?

Comment: The correct filtering for collection by count should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '{{start_datetime}}' and end/dateTime le '{{end_datetime}}' and attendees/$count ne 0` but it returns the error `The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes`. I guess is not supported to filter events by count of attendees.

Comment: I believe @user2250152 was on the right track, but it is missing either $count=true or some eventual consistency header to make it work please see if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http) helps. Something in these lines `~/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/$count eq 0&$count=true`

Comment: Header consistencylevel:eventual with $count=true at the end of the query doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 1):

When posting this on *25-02-2023* it is not supported to combine the `$filter` operator with the `$count` operator on the `attendees` property of an `event` in microsoft graph api.

Seeing as running this query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/$count ne 0&$count=true` in the [online graph exlorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) works fine, but doing the same for events like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=assignedLicenses/$count ne 0&$count=true` doesn't work. and results in this

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
        "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes."
    }
}
```

The microsoft documentation states that if you want support for using the `$filter` on a not supported property you can request it [here](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR_yN8EPoGo5OpR1hgmCp1XxUMENJRkNQTk5RQkpWTE44NEk2U0RIV0VZRy4u)