# Are lambda filters on subproperties of calendar event collections allowed?

Tags: lambda, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

The documentation about [lambda operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) has some examples of filtering on subproperties that work fine in Graph Explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=imAddresses/any(i:i eq 'admin@contoso.com')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(s:s/skuId eq 184efa21-98c3-4e5d-95ab-d07053a96e67)
```

But queries like these on calendar event complex property collections give me 'invalid filter' error messages:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=attendees/any(e:e/emailAddress eq '')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=location/any(i:i/address eq 'here')
```

A query on the simple event *string* collection 'categories' works:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=categories/any(i:i eq 'something')
```

Are lambda filters on subproperties of calendar event collections (not) allowed?
Is my query syntax incorrect?

(Tested with `consistencylevel:eventual` header, which seems to be unnecessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1771?msclkid=fb1d8df8b7fb11ec8238d3ee26457d27#issuecomment-410301969) comment Graph API doesn't support filter events by attendees.

For filtering events by `location` and its `displayName` use

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=location/displayName eq 'Microsoft Teams Meeting'
```

But filtering events by `locations` returns empty results for me

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=locations/any(e:e/displayName eq 'Microsoft Teams Meeting')
```

From my experience filtering Graph API resources by a collection property differs from resource to resource. Sometimes it's working fine sometimes it's not supported.

Comment: Ah! I overlooked that attendees/emailAddress is another complex type. I would have to drilldown to attendees/emailAddress/address and as your link points out "*Microsoft Graph doesn't support drilling down multiple levels of relationships like this (a/emailAddress/address). You cannot only filter one relationship "hop" from the parent resource.*"

Comment: ... which means that my attempt to look at attendees in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75546082/how-to-retrieve-only-meetings?noredirect=1#comment133294296_75546082 will always fail.

Comment: "*Sometimes it's working fine sometimes it's not supported*" Bummer